# Metrizable subspace of Topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Prove that a metrizable complete(w.r.t. metric induced) subspace Y  of a topological vector space  X is closed ?
I proceeded as take x from closure of Y there there is a seq Xn in Y converging to x.since Y is complete this implies x. Belong to Y hence proved.but a long proof was given in functional analysis by Walter Rudin  p.n.21 .
What is wrong with this proof ? Help me

Comment: If $X $ is metrizable your argument is okay. But if it is not, there need not be a sequence converging to the given point in the closure but only a net or a filter.

Comment: Can you give me some example,favouring your argument.and counterexample ?i can understand from there.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof idea (though it's stated poorly) would work if $X$ were metrisable. In general it need not be and Cauchy-ness of a sequence is not defined by a metric in $X$. In general you do not need to have a sequence $x_n$ from $Y$ converging to $x \in \overline{Y}$.

Comment: I don't have mathematical symobls keyboard or anything,so have to stated like this,sorry for that.can you giev me an example of a topogical vector spece whose subspace metrizable but itself not ?

Comment: @ManishBhan $C_p(X)$ (real-continuous functions on $X$ in the pointwise topology) for $X$ uncountable has many metrisable subspaces, but is not itself metrisable.